# Why a new batch is triggered without getting any new offsets in streaming source?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have multiple spark structured streaming jobs and the usual behaviour that I see is that a new batch is triggered only when there are any new offsets in Kafka which is used as source to create streaming query.

But when I run [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredSessionization.scala) example which demonstrates arbitrary stateful operations using `mapGroupsWithState` , then I see that a new batch is triggered even if there is no new data in Streaming source. Why is it so and can it be avoided?

**Update-1**
I modified the above example code and remove state related operation like updating/removing it. Function simply outputs zero. But still a batch is triggered every 10 seconds without any new data on netcat server.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming._

object Stateful {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val host = "localhost"
    val port = "9999"

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredSessionization")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // Create DataFrame representing the stream of input lines from connection to host:port
    val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("socket")
      .option("host", host)
      .option("port", port)
      .option("includeTimestamp", true)
      .load()

    // Split the lines into words, treat words as sessionId of events
    val events = lines
      .as[(String, Timestamp)]
      .flatMap { case (line, timestamp) =>
        line.split(" ").map(word => Event(sessionId = word, timestamp))
      }

    val sessionUpdates = events
      .groupByKey(event => event.sessionId)
      .mapGroupsWithState[SessionInfo, Int](GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout) {

        case (sessionId: String, events: Iterator[Event], state: GroupState[SessionInfo]) =>
          0
      }

    val query = sessionUpdates
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("update")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}

case class Event(sessionId: String, timestamp: Timestamp)

case class SessionInfo(
                        numEvents: Int,
                        startTimestampMs: Long,
                        endTimestampMs: Long)
```

Comment: Whatever the case, batch 0 will always be triggered even if there is no data in kafka. Any subsequent triggers should not be triggered without new data in kafka.

Comment: Yes, but in this example new batches are being triggered even if there is no new data in streaming source. Not just batch zero but subsequent batches too.

Comment: Strange, can you paste your code sample.

Comment: It is the same example that I am trying to run which I mentioned in description. I mentioned Kafka by mistake. Streaming source is netcat server. But with Kafka as source, it is same behaviour as netcat

Comment: I think this is because of Trigger. You can try without using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the empty batches showing up is the usage of Timeouts within the mapGroupsWithState call.

According to the book "Learning Spark 2.0" it says:

> "The next micro-batch will call the function on this timed-out key even if there is not data for that key in that micro.batch. [...] Since the timeouts are processed during the micro-batches, the timing of their execution is imprecise and depends heavily on the trigger interval [...]."

As you have set the timeout to be `GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout` it aligns with your trigger time of the query which is 10 seconds. The alternative would be to set the timeout based on event time (i.e. `GroupStateTimeout.EventTimeTimeout`).

The ScalaDocs on [GroupState](https://people.apache.org/%7Epwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.GroupState) provide some more details:

> When the timeout occurs for a group, the function is called for that group with no values, and GroupState.hasTimedOut() set to true.

Comment: Mike, As I mentioned, this behaviour is only observed when using mapGroupWithState. Without that, Even with trigger in place, it doesn’t increment batch Id. A batch is still triggered every 10s but you will see same batch id every 10s if there is no new data.

Comment: Spark version is 2.4.6

Comment: May be I need to better phrase the question and be specific on describing the situation. What I meant by triggering a “new” batch was that batch id getting incremented without new data

Comment: Thanks @mike . That make sense. If you can update your answer then I can accept it as solution for posterity.